# webrtc: Rollback peerconnection's signalling state to stable

Tags: android, webrtc

as the title suggest, I want to rollback the `PeerConnection's` `SignalingState` to `stable` from `HAVE_LOCAL_OFFER` after an upgrade from audio-only call to audio-video call fails.

When I try to upgrade audio-only call to audio-video call, the rest call to signalling server fails and now the `PeerConnection's` `SignallingState` is `HAVE_LOCAL_OFFER` (since I have already set the local description) but I don't have the remote sdp so now I want to rollback the `SignallingState` to `stable`. I got this https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#idl-def-RTCSdpType.rollback but this seems to be not supported in Android WebRTC stack.

Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi I am stuck with Signalling state as Have local offer. Can you please tell me which android Library are you using? Did you happen to receive Localanswer & remoteoffer states?

Comment: The library is the one which is obtained after compiling the WebRTC code for Android on Linux.